# How can I make a straight cut along the bottom of a cabinet table?

Tags: table

I made a table using MDF, but since it had more height than it should I had the unfortunate idea to cut it at home using a Jigsaw tool. When I used it the cut was not completely straight as we can see in the image.

[image: Table mdf]

What I want to do know is to find some solution that repairs or remediates this irregularity, because right know I'm using woods parts to help.

Comment: For future reference: [Trying to cut a straight line with a jigsaw](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/198073/34147)

Answer (score 2):

A straight edge clamped on so the blade just touches the high spot and trim the rest off.

Screw on some trim wood to cover and straighten.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could get a better fence and use a circular saw to level the whole thing off. You could get some 1" x 3"  trim board and make a frame that fits around the bottom. but the table into the frame, level it and screw the frame to the table. Paint the same color and it will look like it was designed that way.

Answer (score 1):

While it won't make it *look* perfect, you can make the table top level using [leveling feet](https://amzn.to/3gRTsEJ):

[image: Leveling feet]

This example is from Amazon, but similar (if not identical) items are available at hardware and big box stores. There are many types - some mount to side/bottom like this one. Some are designed to be screwed vertically into the vertical pieces - that only works if the vertical pieces are relatively thick.

Comment: DV care to explain?

Comment: My guess is that the dv is based on the fact that your answer didn’t address cutting a straight line. What they failed to realize is that raising the unit makes a wobbly cut much less obvious.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate It doesn't answer the title, but it does answer *some solution that repairs or remediates this irregularity*.

Comment: Agree completely with you. (+1 already)